# Why is React UseEffect hook running on page reload

Tags: reactjs

I have a UseEffect hook with a dependency array.

The issue is that the code inside runs **every** time I reload the page.

I have printed the values, so they should not be changing.

Here is the hook:

```
  useEffect(
    function () {
      console.log('This prints on page load every time');
      // Check if the user is upvoting
      if (didUserUpvote) {
        console.log('here');
        incrementUserUpvotes(answer.uidCreated);
        incrementAnswerUpvotes(answer.answerID);
        appendToArrInDoc('answers', answer.answerID, 'upvotedBy', user.uid);
        console.log('done');
      }
    },
    [didUserUpvote, answer.uidCreated, answer.answerID, user.uid]
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The useEffect is running every time you use reload a page because the variables are being initialized at the initial render, causing that useEffect to trigger.

Best way to fix this issue is to use a useRef Boolean (init at true). If it is true, set the useRef to false. If it is false, run the code you have in the useEffect.

Here’s how I would revise your code:

````
const init = useRef(true)
  useEffect(
    function () {
if(init.current){
init.current= false
}else{
      console.log('This prints on page load every time');
      // Check if the user is upvoting
      if (didUserUpvote) {
        console.log('here');
        incrementUserUpvotes(answer.uidCreated);
        incrementAnswerUpvotes(answer.answerID);
        appendToArrInDoc('answers', answer.answerID, 'upvotedBy', user.uid);
        console.log('done');
      }
}
    },
    [didUserUpvote, answer.uidCreated, answer.answerID, user.uid]
  );```
````

Comment: Hi, could you please add some code here? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much! One more thing, do you think you could explain useRef a little more?

Comment: UseRef is a variable like useEffect that will not cause a rerender of the page. Updating useState WILL cause a rerender of the page, while useRef will not. It’s also good to research a bit about useRef as it might be useful to look more into it.